# Does Sql job schedules with same name affect job working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-job

I have a `SQL` job which has stopped working. Every thing was fine. One thing i noticed that there were multiple schedules with same name and different times of the day. I updated the names and give each schedule a unique name. Then i added another schedule in it just to refresh the job and it worked.

I didn't get what was the issue. My question is that does same schedule name affect the SQL job working?

Comment: SQL job? Is this MS SQL Server?

Comment: In theory, if you have multiple jobs and they all of same schedule names, it shouldn't conflict.  The underlying tables in sql server (assuming you're using sql server) does not mark those as unique.

Comment: @jarlh yes, it is SQL Server. I am asking about having same schedule names in a single  sql job